# Cannot find recently published app

Tags: android, publish

I published my first app about an hour ago and I can't find it. I realize it probably takes a while before it'll show up in a search, so I tried linking to it by name using:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ca.rcp.signals

No sign of it.
Any suggestions??
It's called "Canadian Railway Signals".

I realize this question is similar to others that have been posted, except in the other cases linking to their apps directly worked.

Comment: I waited about 12 hours for mine. Also make sure when you search it, scroll down the list because as a new app, it is not going to he right on top.

Comment: the link you provided working for me ..

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided works for me. You just had a to wait a few more minutes.

From the [Publishing Checklist](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html#final-checks):

> Within a few hours, your app will become available to users and your product page will be appear in Google Play for browsing, searching, or linking from your promotional campaigns.

Comment: Sorry for being a pest. I thought the direct link (rather than searching) would have shown up quicker than it did. Now I know for next time.   Thanks!